# Is the abcde tag helpful to spammers?

Tags: discussion, tags

See this (possibly now deleted) question:

[Inpage Installation](https://askubuntu.com/q/914055/595510)

The user just threw `abcde` in the tags list, and thus saved themselves from entering a tag.

Comment: Not particularly so, I think. I'm used to seeing PHP more often in spam posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, that question doesn't look like a spam post. It just looks like a bad question.

Second, a bunch of people (especially new people) have no idea how tags work. This leads to interesting things like users typing `abcde` or populating the tag field with completely useless things because they *think* they need all five tags.

That said, the `abcde` tag is pretty uncommon - even on spam. It has a legitimate purpose, so there's no reason to nuke it or alter how it works.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the clarification.